# OPENCV Compile Error "undefined reference"

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, visual-studio-code

I have a problem to get openCV running on Linux VS Code. I followed the instruction steps, but still fails when compiled on:

```
/tmp/ccEkxgny.o: In function `cv::String::~String()':
cam_usb.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv6StringD2Ev[_ZN2cv6StringD5Ev]+0x14): undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
```

The test code is simple:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    cout << "Test" << endl;
}
```

Whenever the opencv header is removed, the code executes fine.
The c_cpp_properties.json include directory is set up as described in the tutorials, pointing to the correct installation directory:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
**                "/home/XXXX/opencv/include/opencv2/**",**
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/local/include/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

I have also linked the dependencies in the tasks.json:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
**                "-lopencv_core",
                "-lopencv_imgproc",
                "-lopencv_highgui"**
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Still, the error is present.
Unfortunately I can not find any further resolutions  proposals, any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
(Sorry 1st time user on Linux cpp opencv.. :()

Comment: I found a very similar problem to yours here on OpenCV blog:
https://answers.opencv.org/question/173786/opencv330-undefined-reference-to-cvstringdeallocate-in-cvstdhpp/

Here the problem was related to the linker. Maybe it will help you

Comment: Are you still using OpenCV 3.x? `cv::String` has been a typedef for `std::string` for quite a while (slightly over 5 years now, since the release of 4.0), which doesn't have `deallocate` AFAIK.

Comment: I don't see you setting the library search path (`-L` argument to gcc), and your OpenCV seems to be deployed somewhere in your home directory, which is likely not on the default search path. Is it complaining about not finding the OpenCV libraries to link with? Do you happen to have a second copy of OpenCV installed (a different version than the one in your home dir?) somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to **Dan Masek** for highlighting the issue of the old OpenCV Version (3.2), I upgraded to OpenCV4 and installed it to the standard /usr/local/... folder.
Thanks to **fcc** for verifying it works on his setup.

I still encountered some issues after the installation of OpenCV4, so, for anybody having problems on VS Code Linux with additional libs, following hint:

In addition to above, the tasks.json file also needed further amendment:
extend args with the location of the library - **"-I/usr/local/include/opencv4"**
(Note: new location of library after upgrade)

**Complete tasks.json:**

```
{
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: gcc build active file",
        "command": "/usr/bin/gcc",
        "args": [
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "-lopencv_core",
            "-lopencv_imgproc",
            "-lopencv_highgui",
            "-lopencv_videoio",
            "-I/usr/local/include/opencv4"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
    }
],
"version": "2.0.0"
```

Works like a charme now - Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I confirm that this code can compile and run as expected without error for **OpenCV 4.5.3**, using either c++11, c++14, or c++17.

BTW, `using namespace std;` is not a good practice, see [why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C603.6061).